# Django: cannot annotate using prefetch calculated attribute

Tags: django, orm, relational-database

Target is to sum and annotate workingtimes for each employee on a given time range.

models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class WorkTime(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="work_times")

    work_start = models.DateTimeField()
    work_end = models.DateTimeField()
    work_delta = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.work_delta = (self.work_end - self.work_start).seconds
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

getting work times for each employee at a given date range:

```
queryset = Employee.objects.prefetch_related(
                Prefetch(
                    'work_times',
                    queryset=WorkTime.objects.filter(work_start__date__range=("2021-03-01", "2021-03-15"]))
                        .order_by("work_start"),
                    to_attr="filtered_work_times"
                )).all()
```

trying to annotate sum of work_delta to each employee:

```
queryset.annotate(work_sum=Sum("filtered_work_times__work_delta"))
```

This causes a FieldError:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'filtered_work_times' into field. Choices are: first_name, id, work_times
```

How would one proceed from here? Using Django 3.1 btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [filtering on annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations).
I haven't tried, but I think the following code might help you:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Q

Employee.objects.annotate(
    work_sum=Sum(
        'work_times__work_delta',
        filter=Q(work_times__work_start__date__range=["2021-03-01", "2021-03-15"])
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was waaayyy overthinking this. Sometimes looking at a problem for too long and from too close gets one confused. Everything works now. Stay safe.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the `prefetch_related` values in the query because simply the prefetching is done **separately**, Django would first fetch the current objects and then make queries to fetch the related objects so the field you try to refer is not even part of the query you want to add it to.

Instead of doing this simply add a [`filter` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate-filter) keyword argument to your aggregation function:

```
from django.db.models import  Q


start_date = datetime.date(2021, 3, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2021, 3, 15)

result = queryset.annotate(work_sum=Sum("work_times__work_delta", filter=Q(work_times__work_start__date__range=(start_date, end_date))))
```

Comment: Also thank you for the help. You and the other guy are correct and I appreciate your help. Stay safe